# How to pass parameter from a RequestScoped to a ViewScoped bean

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have a simple form where you can input a `String`. When submitting the form, the user is redirected to another page that echos the user input. The first page is using a `RequestScoped` bean whereas the second page is using a `ViewScoped` bean.

First Page:

```
    <h:form>
        Type a String: <h:inputText value="#{requestScopedBean.property}"></h:inputText>
        <h:commandButton value="To View" action="#{requestScopedBean.toViewScopedBean}">
            <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{viewScopedBean.property}" value="#{requestScopedBean.property}" />
            <f:ajax execute="@form" />
        </h:commandButton>
    </h:form>
```

Second Page:

```
    This is the property passed by the requestScoped bean: <h:outputText value="#{viewScopedBean.property}"></h:outputText><br/>
    This is the property created in the PostConstruct: <h:outputText value="#{viewScopedBean.otherProperty}"></h:outputText>
```

I understand why it does not work. When the form is submitted, the `viewScopedBean.property` is set to the correct value but then we switch to another view, so a new `ViewScopedBean` is created. That's why the value from the request is lost.

How do you pass the parameter from page one to page two **without changing the scope of the bean**?

Comment: Can you just pass the string via URL parameter using GET Request (e.g: mydomain.com?myString=helloWorld), or you would think that the string is too long to pass via URL parameter? Or in order maintain information between page, you can store that information in session, and when get to the second page, get it back. I cant image your string would be too long for the Session.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could put the string on the request map when triggering the requestScopedBean action

```
public String toViewScopedBean(String string){
    Map<String,Object> requestMap = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestMap();
    requestMap.put("StringKey", string);
    return "toViewScopedBean";
}
```

and then retrieve the value from the valueScopedBean

```
public String getProperty(){
    Map<String, Object> requestMap = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestMap();
    return (String) requestMap.get("StringKey");
}
```

Comment: I used the `SessionMap` and it's working. Great resources: http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/06/communication-in-jsf.html